# Nvidia RTX 2060 Max Q - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, hdmi

**What is the correct way to install the proprietary drivers for the Nvidia RTX 2060 Max Q?**

Right now, I am using the open source nouveau drivers. But in the past, when I tried from the GUI the other options, it resulted in a mess: lag, hdmi issues with the 2nd display, not being able to start the session, and so on.

The second part of the question is, should I? Will I benefit from installing the proprietary drivers, or it is fine keep the nouveau drivers?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1:** @mikemikewhatever I selected the 1st option, installed the drivers, rebooted, and I got a black screen. Then I had to reboot, enter recovery mode, purge everything from nvidia, and restart again with the nouveau drivers.

It wasn't a surprise, since this is not the first time that I have tried this. The only difference, is that I will share on this post a  screenshot of the result.

Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, didn't work.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** I tried this time on the terminal (sudo apt install nvidia-driver-530), and it worked (obviously only on xorg session), but with a caveat. Now the 2nd display (hdmi) doesn't work at all. But I guess it is a step forward.

So, the following question should be at this point, **how do I make my 2nd display be recognized?** This is something new, and it doesn't happen with the nouveau drivers, just with the proprietary drivers installed.

I will be open to suggestions and possible solutions. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 3:** I disabled secure boot (UEFI/BIOS) and now the 2nd display gets detected. Afterwards, I only had to recalibrate the colours.

Why all of this happened? No idea. But I will leave this post open, since I am honestly not sure that everything is working 100% and I might have to check again for something, so I will pay attention to this post. Thanks everyone.

Comment: What version of Nvidia driver did you install, which caused issues? Have you tried nvidia-driver-530-open?

Comment: Frankly, I don't remember, since I did that like two months ago, and 4 months ago. But basically I clicked on the first option, then the 2nd, and so on. Among the issues that I had back then, the most "acceptable" (sort of) was the one that didn't recognize my 2nd display. On another occasion, I wasn't even able to initiate the session, and I had to purge EVERY nvidia package from the command line. The experience was bad enough to just keep the nouveau drivers active, plus wayland, since installing any proprietary drivers from nvidia will force me to switch to xorg.

Comment: What I want to do is to install the right package (at this point, I don't know which one is) from GUI or the terminal. To have the option to properly use my GPU on the xorg session; I would prefer wayland, but I know that it is not possible at the moment.

Comment: 1. The answer is in the screenshot you posted. 2. Yes.

Comment: @mikewhatever what all due respect, I wouldn't be making this post if clicking on one of the options available on the GUI did work as expected. Now, assuming that you really know the answer, and are willing to help, please tell me which one of those should I choose. Because, I will update this post afterwards with the outcome. So, everyone will know if it works, or if it doesn't.

Comment: To be very clear, the Ubuntu Drivers program, of which you've posted a screenshot above is , in fact, the right way to install a proprietary Nvidia driver on Ubuntu. If it doesn't work, then file a bug report. There is no hidden or better other way.

Comment: @mikewhatever I agree. Made it a full answer though. It was a bit large for a comment :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct way to install the proprietary drivers for the Nvidia RTX 2060 Max Q?

There are several ways but -none- are the correct way. All are correct and it is just that some are less typing, some are more informative, some have less or more different drivers. In general the drivers are the same software if their version number are the same.

Start by disabling secure boot. Secure boot hinders addressing BIOS.

The way to install nVidia drivers is to remove all traces of older installs.

```
sudo apt autoremove nvidia* --purge
sudo /usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall
sudo /usr/local/cuda-X.Y/bin/cuda-uninstall
```

1st one removes all previous versions if installed through apt. The 2nd one removes all traces of previous installs if installed using a run file. The 3rd removes all traces when installed through the CUDA toolkit. Pick one of the three.

Update and upgrade:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then check what your card is with

```
lspci | grep -e VGA
```

Check the [nvidia](https://www.nvidia.com/) site for support for your card.

Possible ways for installing in order of preference.

Use the new tool (this is likely not in a lot of FAQs at the moment but it is currently really the easiest method for every possible situation: desktop, server, from grub rescue):

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

It will list a bunch of driver. Pick a suitable one. Often the driver closest (up or down a version) is best.This will pick the one the system believes is best:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

And this would install a specific one you pick:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-530
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525
sudo apt install nvidia-headless-525
```

3 examples. The third one is if you want to run headless (so w/o a display). Reboot afterwards.

Alternative:

Desktop method: Select the “Additional Drivers” application. Pick one, and reboot.

Alternative 2:

Using a PPA

```
 sudo apt install software-properties-common -y
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa -y
sudo apt update
```

Then use the `ubuntu-drivers devices` command from the 1st option and it will include all the drivers from the PPA.

Alternative 3:

CUDA install. It is not the most friendly install.

Dependencies:

```
sudo apt install dirmngr ca-certificates software-properties-common apt-transport-https dkms curl -y
```

Find the correct key at [CUDA repos](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/) This does 22.04 (sticking to LTS :) ):

```
curl -fSsL https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub | sudo gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-drivers.gpg > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Add the repo:

```
echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-drivers.gpg] https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-drivers.list
```

Update

```
sudo apt update
```

and this will list all added drivers.

```
apt search nvidia-driver-*
```

Use apt to install (this is also the same as mentioned before (1 example):

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525
```

> The second part of the question is, should I? Will I benefit from installing the proprietary drivers, or it is fine keep the nouveau drivers?

Sort of. Yes the nVidia drivers are quicker but you will not notice it if all you do is use the desktop, play around the web, watch video (the generic stuff will all do).

There are some tools where a graphics driver shine with a good driver. Blender but that is not for most of us. Games are but Ubuntu (/Linux) is still not really a gaming operating system. Yes, I play Demon's Souls on my Ubuntu but even the PS3 emulators are not 100%. Steam, Proton and the likes (but no I do not include wine in that though PoL is getting better and better) are very good attempts to gain traction but it will take some time before game content creators use Linux as the start and not Windows.

> I disabled secure boot (UEFI/BIOS) and now the 2nd display gets detected. Afterwards, I only had to recalibrate the colours.

> Why all of this happened?

Drivers address your hardware. Secure boot is a windows tools that locks your system out from addressing hardware unless it has a key that is accepted.

This is [Linus' official stance](https://www.zdnet.com/article/torvalds-clarifies-linuxs-windows-8-secure-boot-position/) on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to give such a complete response.